# Buttons position

Tags: mobile-application

I'm developing a "dictionary-like" app, with a list of lemmas, definitions and other infos. I was thinking about the wasted spaces for the footbar (1st image). It could be annoying in case of long scrollable pages (all those pages are pretty long).

So maybe I can find a way to completely remove that *fixed* footbar.
In this context, I'm pretty sure a star icon means "add to bookmarks" to the avg users (so maybe there is no need to add a description "bookmark"). The "graph" icon can be moved too. Those are **3** options, which one do you prefer?

[image]

**Edit**: I changed the screenshots, the previous ones hadn't the share icon. I also added a 3rd option for the graph button.

Comment: I doubt any of us can predict what will work best for your users. (Thus the "opinion-based" votes to close.) Your best bet is to do some quick tests on some mockups.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer right side image and make sure to alert/notify the user that he/she bookmarked the definitions or not by changing icon states. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you prefer the rightside. Could you expand on your answer?

Comment: Because it's not looking clumsy.
Every elements placed in a right place with good accessibility.
Only thing I found is the icon and text which you are using inside round shape is not clear.

Comment: If you can - place your reasoning in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trending towards option 2 for the bookmark option. The bookmark icon is nicely located always in the same position at the top. One thing I would be careful about here is the vicinity of the button. Extra space between buttons is important otherwise the user will have trouble tapping on the correct icon/button. To be assessed and tested in the screen design and prototyping.

Regarding the graph button. It's hard to say because I don't know how important it is in the context of the content. But in general the location of the button in option 2 i'm also trending towards. Again it's hard to say with such a wireframe, but when I would work on the screen design I would definitely try a simple text link as a full on C2A might overpower in terms of visual hierarchy the content itself if you know what I mean.

Comment: I edited the mocks, I forgot to add the share icon (maybe 3 icons makes a different perception). I honestly didn't understand your last statement: 
 what's C2A? The "graph" links to the visual representation (node graph) of the lemma in terms of relations with other lemmas. It's pretty important, but the relevant infos are obviously shown in details here in the lemma page.